# How to install wine on aarch 64

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, 64-bit

I have aarch64 (amd64) architecture and I am wanting to install wine.
Is it possible to install it from repository?
I have imported key of repository and added i386 architecture already.
After it I writed in command line

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
```

All successful!

Then I updated all packages with sudo apt update and tried to install wine but I got error.

```
dextop@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install winehq-stableReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable:i386 : Depends: wine-stable:i386 (= 4.0.1~xenial) but it 
is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: "held broken packages" is a *version* problem, not an arch problem - you have simply chosen a version of Wine that is incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. You can avoid this by simply installing Wine from the Ubuntu repositories instead of a third-party repository. One easy way to get the latest version of Wine is to migrate to Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 2):

`aarch64` is **not** `x86_64` / `amd64`.  `aarch64` is for [ARM v8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#AArch64), ie: Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

Wine recommends, or requires, the installment and availability of both `amd64` and `i386` libraries.  This means you'll have to follow instructions on installing Wine, which includes enabling *multilib*/[*multiarch*](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).  After reading about this, and the consequences, you could add `i386` to your `amd64` system with the following command:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt update
```

Even after adding the WineHQ repository, the packages there may need `i386` packages from Ubuntu and other sources.  This is why you must perform this step even after adding WineHQ repository, explaining why it is the first step in the [WineHQ Ubuntu Documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

After taking another look, I do not see the command you showed us anywhere in this document.  Did you try following some other instructions after these didn't work?  Why are you running your version of the `apt-add-repository` command, vs the one listed by WineHQ?

---

For anybody wanting to run Wine on `aarch64`, it is possible, but likely not worth the trouble.  The instructions will most certainly not be the same as an `amd64` system, and you'll mess up an `aarch64` system by adding `amd64` or `i386` packages.  You may consider running Windows 10 directly and look into [Microsoft IoT Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/downloads).

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (64 bit). I am trying to use sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (64 bit). I am trying to use `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'` I get `N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'`
Because of it I add [arch=amd64]

Comment: @АлеександрПолещук What kind of computer do you have? What's the output of `uname -mp`?

Comment: I have a tablet. dextop@localhost:~$ uname -mp
aarch64 aarch64

Comment: There are I posted my tries  in comments. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156837/command-for-adding-of-repository-wine

Comment: @АлеександрПолещук Forget about wine on ARM64. It's possible, yet not very useful as you won't find many windows programs compiled for that CPU. Nor will you find wine precompiled for Arm, you will probably have to build it yourself. You **cannot** install the AMD64 or i386 version of wine. ARM is a **totally** different CPU.